# Erro em alguns computadores ao tentar capturar a tensão do processador pelo WMI

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

Em apenas alguns computadores ao executar o meu programa de especificação de hardware ele acusa um erro na linha 155.

```
public static String voltage()
            {
                String Ic = String.Empty;
                foreach (var item in new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select from Win32_Processor").Get())
            {
                   Ic = (decimal.Parse(item["CurrentVoltage"].ToString()) / 10).ToString() + " v";
                    if(Ic == "0")
                    {
                        return "~";
                    }
                }
                return Ic;
            }
```

> Linha 155 abaixo.

```
Ic = (decimal.Parse(item["CurrentVoltage"].ToString()) / 10).ToString() + " v";
```

E impede que meu programa continue rodando normalmente mas é apenas em alguns computadores, no geral o programa roda sem erros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez acesso de administrador nesses computadores?

Comment: Ricardo não pois em outros computadores também estavam sem acesso administrador.

Comment: Qual é a exception lançada? o que tem dentro de detalhes ali? Cola lá na pergunta, vai ajudar a tentar descobrir

Comment: Aparentemente a linha está causando uma Exception que o código não tratou. Pode ser indice não existente em *item*, ou seu valor está vazio, etc que pode ser causado pela falta da informação. Verifique que tipo de processador e placa mãe o sistema está rodando, as permissões de execução e melhore o código adicionando um tratamento de exceção.

Comment: Pra mim, o erro mais provável de acontecer é item["CurrentVoltage"] estar NULO! ou item está nulo.

Comment: Ricardo infelizmente não vou poder mostrar os detalhes pois estou distante do computador que está dando o erro, mas quando eu cliquei ele informa que é na voltage() na linha 155.

Marcos Regis ok mais então como eu posso adicionar um tratamento de exceção antes de dar erro?

Comment: Se você não conseguir acesso a maquina com problemas (estou entendo que é maquina de cliente) então eu colocaria um try catch no bloco e faria um log, não é a solução, mas você via conseguir pegar o que está acontecendo, o tratamento de null que o @PauloHDSousa já pode até ser feito antes de qualquer coisa também.

Comment: @G.Carlo você não deve adicionar tratamento para a exceção, isso é gambiarra, da grossa. Você deve consertar o erro de programação presente no código. O qual não podemos ajudar por falta de informações.

Comment: Voltagens, velocidade de ventoinha e temperatura raramente tem interface exposta no WMI. Normalmente é necessário um software de terceiros para expor estes dados. As pouquissimas combinações de hardware que tem esta informação diretamente pelo windows são meras exceções.